# How to show a result that will include records spanning over 2 days

Tags: sql-server, sql-date-functions

I have a database that I need to query that has spans over a night shif running through the morning ie. 10pm - 6am.

The problem is that if I run the following query

```
 select * from F305BatchLog 
where  StartDate between '2018-01-10' And '2018-01-11' 
and StartTime between '22:00:00' And '06:00:00'
order by TimeStamp asc
```

It doesn't give me any results . I basically need to run a query starting from a specific date and if it overlaps to the next morning until 6am will include those results

My desired result should be

```
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    1   2018-01-10  Totalised   118.9988174 2018-01-10 23:15:57.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    2   2018-01-10  Totalised   119.4488068 2018-01-10 23:23:41.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    3   2018-01-10  Totalised   120.8987885 2018-01-10 23:30:50.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    4   2018-01-10  Totalised   121.2987823 2018-01-10 23:37:01.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    5   2018-01-10  Totalised   120.8487854 2018-01-10 23:44:33.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    6   2018-01-10  Totalised   120.7487946 2018-01-10 23:54:09.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    7   2018-01-11  Totalised   121.0987854 2018-01-11 00:01:24.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    8   2018-01-11  Totalised   119.5988083 2018-01-11 00:09:41.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    9   2018-01-11  Totalised   119.5488129 2018-01-11 00:17:22.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    10  2018-01-11  Totalised   120.1488037 2018-01-11 00:24:30.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    11  2018-01-11  Totalised   120.598793  2018-01-11 00:31:00.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    12  2018-01-11  Totalised   120.1488037 2018-01-11 00:37:54.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    13  2018-01-11  Totalised   121.1487885 2018-01-11 00:44:13.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    14  2018-01-11  Totalised   121.0987854 2018-01-11 00:50:45.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    15  2018-01-11  Totalised   120.4987946 2018-01-11 00:57:37.000
PC4424 SMR                                          F305    16  2018-01-11  Totalised   119.6488037 2018-01-11 01:04:26.000
```

Comment: add a little sample data and your desired output please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for evening and morning separately:

```
select * from F305BatchLog 
where  (StartDate between '2018-01-10' And '2018-01-11' 
        and StartTime between '22:00:00' And '23:59:59.9999')
   or  (StartDate between '2018-01-11' and '2018-01-12'
        and StartTime between '00:00:00' and '06:00:00')
order by TimeStamp asc
```

Better yet, assuming TimeStamp is a `DateTime` column:

```
select * from F305BatchLog
where TimeStamp between '2018-01-10 22:00:00' and '2018-01-11 06:00:00'
order by TimeStamp asc
```

What you should *not* do is combine the StartDate and StartTime into one datetime variable using `DATEADD` or some other function. That will cause your query to be non-SARGable and ruin the chance of using any index to optimize it.

Comment: Thanks Ross . Working fine now .Appreciate it